# How do i access data from redis encoded wth msgpack?

Tags: python, redis, msgpack

I've got some `enc_data` with `msgpack` coming from `redis`.
I've set up my sentinel and connection as follow:

```
sentinel = Sentinel([('localhost','26379')], decode_responses=False)          
conn = sentinel.master_for('foo', socket_timeout=0.5, decode_responses=False)
```

I used `decode_responses` in both places since i cant determine which one actually works.
Next I'm reading my data and decode it

```
enc_data = conn.get('msgpack:data:key')
data = msgpack.loads(enc_data)
```

What I see

```
data.keys()
########################################
dict_keys([b'key_0', b'key_1', b'key_2', b'key_3'])
```

However

```
print(data.get('key_0'))
#######################################
None
```

Could you point out what I'm doing wrong decoding this data or accessing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...

```
class Unpacker(object):
    """Streaming unpacker.

    :param bool raw:
        If true, unpack msgpack raw to Python bytes (default).
        Otherwise, unpack to Python str (or unicode on Python 2) by decoding
        with UTF-8 encoding (recommended).
        Currently, the default is true, but it will be changed to false in
        near future.  So you must specify it explicitly for keeping backward
        compatibility.

        *encoding* option which is deprecated overrides this option.
```

This option needs to be set to `False` and everything works like magic.

```
data = msgpack.loads(enc_data, raw=False)
```